# Meaning of this complex declaration

Tags: c++, function, pointers, return

consider the following declaration:

```
double(*foo(double (*)(double, double[]), double)) (double, ...)
```

- Describe in English the type of foo.

This is an Homework problem. My analysis is:

```
"foo is a function pointer to a function that has as it's first argument, 
another function pointer to a function that returns a double and takes a 
double and an array of doubles."
```

Is it right? Can anyone simplify and specify the correct/exact representation in English? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The type of `foo` is "over-specified due to horrendous code that will not pass code review in my team, and actually possibly get you fired". Any professional can verify it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), remembering to go **right**, left, right, left, etc., always doing whatever is in parentheses before exiting them:

```
double(*foo(double (*)(double, double[]), double)) (double, ...)  
        ^^^
```

`foo` is a...

```
double(*foo(double (*)(double, double[]), double)) (double, ...)  
           ^------------------------------------^
```

`foo` is a function...

```
double(*foo(double (*)(double, double[]), double)) (double, ...)  
                    ^
```

`foo` is a function taking a pointer to a...

```
double(*foo(double (*)(double, double[]), double)) (double, ...)  
                      ^----------------^
```

`foo` is a function taking a pointer to a function...

```
double(*foo(double (*)(double, double[]), double)) (double, ...)  
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`foo` is a function taking a pointer to a function taking a `double` and a pointer to a `double` ("array of doubles" if you want to sugar-coat it)...

```
double(*foo(double (*)(double, double[]), double)) (double, ...)  
            ^^^^^^                        ^^^^^^
```

`foo` is a function taking a (pointer to a function taking a `double` and a pointer to a `double` that returns a `double`) and a `double`...

```
double(*foo(double (*)(double, double[]), double)) (double, ...)  
       ^
```

`foo` is a function taking a (pointer to a function taking a `double` and a pointer to a `double` that returns a `double`) and a `double` that returns a pointer to...

```
double(*foo(double (*)(double, double[]), double)) (double, ...) 
                                                   ^-----------^
```

`foo` is a function taking a (pointer to a function taking a `double` and a pointer to a `double` that returns a `double`) and a `double` that returns a pointer to a function...

```
double(*foo(double (*)(double, double[]), double)) (double, ...) 
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`foo` is a function taking a (pointer to a function taking a `double` and a pointer to a `double` that returns a `double`) and a `double` that returns a pointer to a function taking a `double` and anything...

```
double(*foo(double (*)(double, double[]), double)) (double, ...) 
^^^^^^
```

`foo` is a function taking a (pointer to a function taking a `double` and a pointer to a `double` that returns a `double`) and a `double` that returns a pointer to a function taking a `double` and anything that returns a `double`.

Plugging the whole thing into [cdecl](http://cdecl.org) gives me this (except that it doesn't like ellipsis parameters):

> declare foo as function (pointer to function (double, array of double) returning double, double) returning pointer to function (double, ...) returning double

Answer (score 1):

Please look at it this way:

```
  double(*foo(double (*)(double, double[]), double)) (double, ...);
  == double(*foo(FUNC_PTR, double)) (double, ...)
  where FUNC_PTR is of the form => double(*)(double first_arg, double[] second_arg)
```

Comment: Please answer the question